# How to store guest customer details in database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on an appointment booking module where I use one user table for admins, staff, and registered customers. The module is handled with roles and user authentication also.

**User Table Structure:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xztA.png

I need to add guest customer booking (**Fields:** Name, Email, Phone No.).

My doubt is whether I need to add a guest customer to the separate table or the user table.

And I need to show both guest customers and registered customers on the customer's page of the admin panel.

Please help me... Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is more of a design question so it's really more up to you how you want your app to work

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a customer_type column in your table, in which the id of his customer_type will appear.
Which will be easy for you to know which customer is.

Like - 1- admin, 2-staff, 3-guest customer, 4- registered customer

Hope this helps you.